# How to use '($RE{num}{real})' as a regex?

Tags: regex, perl

In the following code, I want to make `g` and `f` print the same output. The difference is `($RE{num}{real})$` is given as a string. Does anybody how now to convert it to a regex?

```
~/linux/test/perl/library/Regexp/Common/%RE/num/real$ cat main1.pl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use FindBin;
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/.";

use Regexp::Common;

sub f {
  my $x = shift;
  $x =~ s/^($RE{num}{real})$/$1 is real/;
  print "$x\n";
}

f("1.5");
f("15f");
f("1e5");
f(".1e5");
f("a");

my $regex_str='($RE{num}{real})';
#Neither of the following work.
#$regex_str=eval $regex_str;
#$regex_str=qr{$regex_str};
sub g {
  my $x = shift;
  $x =~ s/^$regex_str$/$1 is real/;
  print "$x\n";
}

g("1.5");
g("15f");
g("1e5");
g(".1e5");
g("a");


~/linux/test/perl/library/Regexp/Common/%RE/num/real$ ./main1.pl 
1.5 is real
15f
1e5 is real
.1e5 is real
a
1.5
15f
1e5
.1e5
a
```

Comment: [`use re 'debug'`](http://perldoc.perl.org/re.html#'debug'-mode "perldoc re") ( or `perl -Mre=debug main1.pl` )

Answer (score 2):

```
my $regex_str="($RE{num}{real})";
```

or

```
my $regex_str=qr/($RE{num}{real})/;
```

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes in Perl do not interpolate variables. Use double quotes to interpolate a variable. To create a regular expression, though, you may use the `qr//` operator:

```
my $regex = qr/$RE{num}{real}$/;
if ( $x !~ $regex ) {
```

Comment: Is `$RE` a 2D hash table in the `Regexp::Common` package?

Comment: @Andomar: Checking the [documentation](http://p3rl.org/Regexp::Common), it seems so (%RE is the hash, in fact, not $RE).

Comment: @choroba: I have to start with the string '$RE{num}{real}'.

Comment: @user1424739: See [String::Interpolate](http://p3rl.org/String::Interpolate) or the evil [eval](http://p3rl.org/eval).

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you have two `$` tokens at the end:

```
my $regex_str='$RE{num}{real}$';
...
if( $x !~ /^$regex_str$/) {
```

Comment: Fixed the double `$` typo. Problem still exist.

Comment: Actually two `$` isn't really a problem. The real problem is the single quotes `'` around `$RE{num}{real}`.

Comment: @BradGilbert: Looks like you're right, a `$` doesn't consume anything, so `$$` matches where `$` matches